# Build NuGet package for .Net Standard 2.0 lib with Cake

Tags: msbuild, .net-standard, cakebuild

I have created a class library based on .Net Standard 2.0 and I build the project/solution with Cake, but I cannot find how to build NuGet package for that library. NuGetPack doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You really have two options.  `NuGetPack` will continue to work, I use this approach on a couple of Cake Addins that I maintain.  Could you explain more details about the issue that you are seeing?

The other option would be to use the `DotNetCorePack` alias.  You can see this in action in this file (which is part of the Cake.Recipe set of scripts):

https://github.com/cake-contrib/Cake.Recipe/blob/develop/Cake.Recipe/Content/nuget.cake

And it is also documented here:

https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.DotNetCore/DotNetCoreAliases/0F7A518E

```
var projects = GetFiles(BuildParameters.SourceDirectoryPath + "/**/*.csproj")
    - GetFiles(BuildParameters.SourceDirectoryPath + "/**/*.Tests.csproj");

var settings = new DotNetCorePackSettings {
    NoBuild = true,
    Configuration = BuildParameters.Configuration,
    OutputDirectory = BuildParameters.Paths.Directories.NuGetPackages,
    ArgumentCustomization = (args) => {
        if (BuildParameters.ShouldBuildNugetSourcePackage)
        {
            args.Append("--include-source");
        }
        return args
            .Append("/p:Version={0}", BuildParameters.Version.SemVersion)
            .Append("/p:AssemblyVersion={0}", BuildParameters.Version.Version)
            .Append("/p:FileVersion={0}", BuildParameters.Version.Version)
            .Append("/p:AssemblyInformationalVersion={0}", BuildParameters.Version.InformationalVersion);
    }
};

foreach (var project in projects)
{
    DotNetCorePack(project.ToString(), settings);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NuGetPack requires nuget.exe 4.4.x or newer for .NET Standard to work properly, that said there's also alternatives to using nuget.exe.

If you're using the .NET Core Cli then you use the [DotNetCorePack](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.DotNetCore/DotNetCoreAliases/0F7A518E) alias.

If you're using MSBuild to build, MSBuild now for new SDK csproj has a `Pack` target, which could look something like this:

```
var configuration           = Argument("configuration", "Release");
FilePath solution           = MakeAbsolute(File("./src/MySolution.sln"));
DirectoryPath artifacts     = MakeAbsolute(Directory("./artifacts"));
var version = //some version login i.e. GitVersion
var semVersion = //some version login i.e. GitVersion

Func<MSBuildSettings,MSBuildSettings>
    commonSettings         = settings => settings
                                .UseToolVersion(MSBuildToolVersion.VS2017)
                                .SetConfiguration(configuration)
                                .SetVerbosity(Verbosity.Minimal)
                                .WithProperty("PackageOutputPath", artifacts.FullPath)
                                .WithProperty("VisualStudioVersion", "15.0")
                                .WithProperty("Version", semVersion)
                                .WithProperty("AssemblyVersion", version)
                                .WithProperty("FileVersion", version);

Task("Clean")
  .Does(() =>
  {
    //some clean logic
  });

Task("Restore-NuGet-Packages")
    .IsDependentOn("Clean")
    .Does(() =>
{
    NuGetRestore(solution,
        new NuGetRestoreSettings {
            Verbosity = NuGetVerbosity.Quiet
            });
});

Task("Build")
    .IsDependentOn("Restore-NuGet-Packages")
    .Does(() =>
{
    MSBuild(solution, settings => commonSettings(settings).WithTarget("Build"));
});



Task("Create-NuGet-Package")
    .IsDependentOn("Build")
    .Does(() =>
{
     MSBuild(project,
        settings => commonSettings(settings)
                        .WithTarget("Pack")
                        .WithProperty("IncludeSymbols","true"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get `NuGetPack` to work, though that may have been the NuGet exe version (though I was fairly certain it was 4.4.something).

I ended up with the following code in my cake script for packaging Core projects:

```
private void PackCoreProject(string nugetVersion, string outputDirectory, string projectFile)
{
    var settings = GetCorePackSettings(nugetVersion, outputDirectory);
    DotNetCorePack(projectFile, settings);
}

private DotNetCorePackSettings GetCorePackSettings(string nugetVersion, string outputDirectory)
{
    // Version fun with dotnet core... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42797993/package-version-is-always-1-0-0-with-dotnet-pack

    Func<Cake.Core.IO.ProcessArgumentBuilder, Cake.Core.IO.ProcessArgumentBuilder> appendVersionToArgs = 
        new Func<Cake.Core.IO.ProcessArgumentBuilder, Cake.Core.IO.ProcessArgumentBuilder>(_ => 
    {
        return _.Append($"/p:Version={nugetVersion}");
    });

    return new DotNetCorePackSettings
    {
        VersionSuffix = GetNuGetVersionSuffix(),
        OutputDirectory = outputDirectory,
        Configuration = configuration,
        NoBuild = true,
        IncludeSymbols = true,
        IncludeSource = true,
        ArgumentCustomization = appendVersionToArgs,
    };
}

private string GetNuGetVersion()
{
    // If the branch is master or hotfix, build a normal version as these are due for release.
    if (IsReleaseBranch())
    {
        return $"{major}.{minor}.{build}";
    }

    return $"{major}.{minor}.0-{GetNuGetVersionSuffix()}";
}
```

Note I have to manually add the version to the end via the builder function.

The `IsReleaseBranch` method is just a switch that flags `master` or `hotfix` as a valid release branch and anything else as dev, so when a NuGet package version is determined, dev builds are pre-release.