# MSBuild /t:pack Nuget-Package has always the same Version

Tags: tfs, msbuild, .net-core

I am creating a nuget-package with `/t:pack` in my TFS-Build. I can't the use Nuget-Pack-Step, because I am using

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
```

How can I apply my `AssemblyVersion` on the Nuget-Package? Because my Assembly-Version is right, but my Nuget version always remains `1.0.0.0`.

Note I am using a C# file for my assembly information instead of the `.csproj` file.

Is there any possibility to it?

Want to share that [link](https://qanda.tech/tfs/12989/msbuild-t-pack-nuget-package-has-allways-the-same-version).

Comment: https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/blob/10.0.2/SharpSnmpLib/SharpSnmpLib.csproj#L26 The package version comes from the `Version` tag of your project, so you should try to modify that.

Comment: I am using an AssemblyInfo.cs instead of the csproj-file. But I cant find the equivalent to it. Should be sth like [assembly: AssemblyVersion("4.0.0.0")).

Comment: There "should be", but there isn't yet. You can still use a `.nuspec` if you want to (as I have a project using that trick).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The MSBuild-integrated `Pack` target reads its value from MSBuild properties inside the project (`PackageVersion` to be specific, which is defaulted from `Version`, which in turn is defaulted to `VersionPrefix` which in turn may be suffixed by `VersionSuffix`).

There is out-of-the-box support for reading this value from an assembly attribute since the new project format is meant to generate these assembly attributes from the same configuration that determines NuGet package metadata.

However, you can extend the build by adding a custom target to the csproj file that reads the built assembly's identity during `msbuild /t:Pack`:

```
<Project>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <GenerateNuspecDependsOn>$(GenerateNuspecDependsOn);ReadPackageVersionFromOutputAssembly</GenerateNuspecDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="ReadPackageVersionFromOutputAssembly" DependsOnTargets="Build">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="PackAssembly" />
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <PackageVersion>%(PackAssembly.Version)</PackageVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Note that this target will only run on the "full MSBuild", that is `msbuild.exe` on windows (visual studio developer command prompt) or mono 5.2+ on linux/Mac. <strike>This currently does not work for `dotnet pack` (.NET Core version of MSBuild).</strike> UPDATE: This will now work in .NET SDKs 2.1.* and higher since the `GetAssemblyIdentity` task has been added to the cross-platform version of msbuild in 2018.

Comment: Superb Martin. Spent hours on this and your solution solves the problem perfectly.

Answer (score 10):

With current version of MSBuild it is possible to specify `PackageVersion` parameter:

```
msbuild ProjectName.csproj -t:Pack -p:PackageVersion=1.2.3
```